# Angular 7 add directives to dynamically generated html

Tags: angular, dynamic, angular-directive

I use [ngx-codemirror](https://github.com/TypeCtrl/ngx-codemirror) and want to display a [mat-tooltip](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview) when mouse enters a string. 
The way it was done in AngularJS:

```
el = angular.element('.cm-string');
el.attr('uib-tooltip', "Tooltip text");
el.attr('tooltip-append-to-body', 'true');
$compile(el)(scope);
```

Is there a way to attach the [matTooltip] or any directive dynamically?

Comment: No. Angular is compiled, meaning the directives add post-compilation won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import....

 export class AppComponent  { 
   constructor(private injector: Injector) {
     const ourDynamicDiv = document.getElementById('anynewdiv');
     const tooltip: MatTooltip = Injector.create({
        parent: this.injector,
        providers: [
          {
            provide: ElementRef,
            useValue: new ElementRef(ourDynamicDiv)
          },
          {
            provide: MatTooltip,
            useClass: MatTooltip,
            deps: [
              Overlay,
              ElementRef,
              ScrollDispatcher,
              ViewContainerRef,
              NgZone,
              Platform,
              AriaDescriber,
              FocusMonitor,
              MAT_TOOLTIP_SCROLL_STRATEGY,
              Directionality,
              MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
              // HAMMER_LOADER
            ]
          }
        ]
      }).get(MatTooltip);
      tooltip.position = 'above';
      tooltip.message = `message text`;
    }
```

This attaches Material Tooltip to dynamically added element.